# what is full-expression of initialization

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

About the full-expression, there are some quotes in the standard, they are:

> A full-expression is
>
> > 1. an unevaluated operand,
> > 2. a constant-expression,
> > 3. an **init-declarator** or a mem-initializer, including the constituent expressions of the initializer,
> > 4. an invocation of a destructor generated at the end of the lifetime of an object other than a temporary object, or
> > 5. **an expression that is not a subexpression of another expression and that is not otherwise part of a full-expression**.
> >
> >    > For an initializer, performing the initialization of the entity (including evaluating default member initializers of an aggregate) is also considered **part of the full-expression**.

Now, please consider the below code:

```cpp
struct A{
  constexpr A(int){
  }
};
int main(){
 constexpr A t = 0; //#1
}
```

> A constexpr specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as const. Such an object shall have literal type and shall be initialized. In any constexpr variable declaration, the **full-expression of the initialization shall be a constant expression**.

Look at `#1`, it's a declaration, according to the standard, within this declaration, the `init-declarator` is a full-expression, So what's the full-expression of initialization, if it's `A::A(0)` (comprise the conversion), it would be contradict with the bullet point **5** of the full-expression, that's **an expression that is not otherwise part of a full-expression**. Obviously, the `A::A(0)` is part of the full-expression `init-declarator`, Hence `A::A(0)` shouldn't be a full-expression.

If the full-expression of initialization is referred to `init-declarator`, Due to a `init-declarator` is not a **expression**, how does a `init-declarator` could be a constant-expression? I'm very confused here, If my understanding is wrong, what actually the full-expression of initialization is?

Comment: The invocation of `A`'s constructor is part of the *full-expression* comprised of the *init-declarator*, and not a *full-expression* by itself. I don't see any contradictions.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik then what is the full-expression of **initialization** here,such as for `constexpr A t = 0;`

Comment: The standard doesn't use the term "full-expression of initialization". I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  The standard indeed use the term `full-expression of initialization`,  please look at the emphasized part in my question.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see. I agree the wording is unclear.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yup, I have update my question, if you know how to interpret this question, please leave an answers.